# Modify CSV via Script

Tags: csv

I need to modify csv files via automated scripts.  I need help in what direction I should look towards and what language the script should be in

Situation: I have a simple CSV file but I need an automated script that can edit certain fields and fill in blank ones with whatever I specify.  What should my starting point be and what kind of a developer should I look for? Which coding language should he or she be knowledgable at?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are looking for CSVfix, this is a tool for manipulating CSV data in the command shell. Take a look here: https://code.google.com/p/csvfix/

With it you can, among other things:

1. Reorder, remove, split and merge fields
2. Convert case, trim leading & trailing spaces
3. Search for specific content using regular expressions
4. Filter out duplicate data or data on exclusion lists
5. Enrich with data from other sources
6. Add sequence numbers and file source information
7. Split large CSV files into smaller files based on field contents
8. Perform arithmetic calculations on individual fields
9. Validate CSV data against a collection of validation rules

and convert between CSV and fixed format, XML, SQL and DSV

I hope this helps you out,
best regards,
Jürgen Jester